# Rascal/Clair: Unable to access comments from M3

Tags: comments, rascal, clair

I try to iterate over all comments in a C++ source file, but I fail to access M3.comments.

I tried iprintln, for-, switch- and visit-statements.

iprintln(m3) gives the following output:

```
m3(

  |file://bla.c|,

  macroExpansions={},

  methodOverrides={},

  includeDirectives={
    ...
  },

  inactiveIncludes={},

  comments=[

    |file://bla.c|(0,80),

    |file://bla.c|(82,34),

    ...
  ],

  macroDefinitions={},

  includeResolution={
    ...
  })
'''
```

The following code matches

```
visit (m3) { case comments: println("match"); }
```

but I am unable to get the locations.

E.g.

```
visit (m3) { case c:comments: println(c); }
```

gives back "Ambiguous code (internal error), c:comments:".

Next

```
visit (m3) { case comments(c): println("c"); }
```

does not match

And

```
iprintln(m3.comments);
```

gives back "Undeclared field: comments for M3".

How can I access the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can project out the comments by this:

```
theComments = m3Model.comments;
```

That "." expression selects the comments field of the m3 data constructor.

If you want to match a keyword field like `comments` instead, you'd write a pattern like so:

```
m3(comments=theComments) := myM3Model
```

If the field is undeclared, you could declare it like so:

```
data M3(list[loc] comments=[]);
```

However, that should have been in the Claire library declarations already. Please report an issue on GitHub?

Comment: Thanks Jurgen for the fast response. Adding "data M3(list[loc] comments=[]);" in my own code solved the problem. I will submit an issue in GitHub.

Comment: The new release of ClaiR on the update site fixes the issue.